# How to automate cmd bat file to execute command as we paste text?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wget, copy-paste

I am working with wget here. What I want to do is fetch the links as I paste in cmd so that it makes it easy for me not to re-write each line with the links I want wget to fetch.

The common/simple code (in batch) for fetching a website link data is `"wget "http://example.com/example" --no-check-certificate"` or `"wget http://example.com/example --no-check-certificate"` (both works in .bat),
but I want it to be something like `"wget %paste --no-check-certificate"` so that if I paste the link say https://google.com in the command prompt it directly runs is as `"wget "https://google.com" --no-check-certificate"`.
How do I achieve it?

I have tried the normal batch file scripting with the code wget "http://example.com/example" --no-check-certificate, nothing else.

This code works flawlessly in the .bat file:

```
wget "http://example.com/example" --no-check-certificate
```

I explain my query in simple steps:

1. I need a piece of code for batch file that will run the cmd and put it on standby i.e ready for code execution.
2. I will be pasting links via the right-click > paste method.
3. I want the bat file/cmd to execute the code with the link embedded as `wget http://example.com/example --no-check-certificate` where http://example.com/example is the link I pasted in cmd.

Comment: `"%~1"` is probably what you want to replace the URL with, i.e. `wget "%~1" --no-check-certificate`. Alternatively you could prompt for the URL with `Set /P "Enter your URL: "`, the end user can then paste directly at the prompt.

Comment: no, what I want is a script of codes that will run the cmd and will be on standby, as soon as I paste the link it will directly execute the `wget link --no-check-certificate`.

Comment: I got the answer, the answer/script by @Stephan works like a charm. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following batch script.

```
@echo off
:loop
set /p "link=Paste Link "
wget "%link%" --no-check-certificate
goto :loop
```

`set /p` is intended for user input. It also accepts a "paste".